# When texture painting, it affects all textures on the mesh. Instead of the single texture I have selected

Tags: texture-painting

To explain my problem, I'll use this cube.
This cube has 2 textures on it;
[image]

[image]

Both Textures have an 'Image Texture' set as their 'Base Color'.
And the normals have been unwrapped. So ready to texture paint.

Say i wanna paint on the blue texture alone,with a white brush,
this is what would happen;
[image]
As you can see, the red texture gets affected as well.

Is it possible to make this not happen? Or is it something standard to how Blender works?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Select "Single Image" in the "Texture Slots" and then the image of the texture you want. Painting will then only affect that area/image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked :D